# importing libgdx test projects Error

Tags: libgdx, android-library

### Problem

I downloaded the libgdx-master.zip library and unzipped it, then tried to import android tests project in eclipse, doing so gives an exclamation mark which is not a unique error but problems i am facing are below.

### I did following to sort it out, but did not work for me

1. Created libs folder in the project and copied all the jars in that
2. In project properties i added the jar files that come along libgdx-master.zip libray
3. Cleaned the project
4. That is what i do when ever resources conflict or exclamation mark comes in my project

### Errors

1. In the imports: The Classes this test project uses from libgdx-master libray
2. In Project Properties->Java build-> Project-> some missing projects appear
3. I searched a lot about importing the test projects present in this library, but, can only found creating new project to use this library

### What i aspect from the community

1. Importing test projects from the library libgdx-master, any
   tutorial link/guide you used yourself, i tried a lot.
2. Any one who used this library could answer more properly
3. what rating/ranking would you give to use this library for android board game development
4. I know how to import the projects and link the resources, but, in this specific case it did not work for me, if you please answer specifically, i would be grateful.

At the the end i would like to thanks who showed patience to read this.

Comment: What specific URL did you get libgdx-master.zip from?  As far as I know, the official (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html) zip downloads do not include any demos.  If you downloaded the .zip from github, you probably need to run `ant fetch.xml` to download the "native" bits (this is recent change, so it depends on when you downloaded it).

Comment: Thanks! [P.T.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/960524/p-t) for putting me in the in the right direction.